# Misunderstand syntax neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I have some syntax in project C# that using DB neo4j. In this WithParam, I can not understand about its syntax

```
var data = WebApiConfig.GraphClient.Cypher
               .Match("(m:Movie)")
               .Where("m.title =~ {title}")
               .WithParam("title", "(?i).*" + q + ".*")
               .Return<Movie>("m")
               .Results.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should review the [Cypher parameters documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/). Parameters passed with a query are referenceable by a special syntax (the "title" parameter was passed as a parameter, so you would use `$title` to use it in the query, or `{title}` if using the older parameter syntax).

As for the value of the parameter itself, "title" is a regex string. `(?i)` means it's case insensitive, `.*` means match 0 or more characters, then the `q` variable from your code is appended in, followed by another `.*` for matching any additional characters. The place of usage of the parameter uses the regex comparison operator `=~` which interprets the regex string correctly.

This is a case-insensitive comparison, looking for any :Movie nodes with a title property that contains whatever the `q` string is, regardless of case.